# Can a player be replaced after the team is announced for a cricket match?

Tags: rules, cricket

After a team has been named, can any players be replaced?

What is the limit of this replacement? For example, if half the team were injured while warming up, can they be substituted or otherwise swapped out?

Does the same rule apply if this were to happen during the first innings or between innings?

Comment: You've now made this two very different questions. Please choose one of the two and keep the question to just that. (And also don't use block quotes to mark up text).

Comment: I am asking my first question in this.So,Please edit it (or) How can I ask two questions at a time

Comment: If you want two questions, make two posts. If you want three questions, make three posts - *but stop adding additional questions to this post*.

Comment: While there are now three questions, they are naturally and closely linked, such that a good answer to the first will mostly or fully answer the others. That "bridge" between the first and (currently) third was not apparent earlier. @PhilipKendall

Comment: The trouble is that the answer to the first and second questions depends on exactly when it happens, which is very different to the answer to the third question.

Answer (score 3):

Once the team has been named and exchanged the players can not be replaced without the agreement of the other captain.

If the captain allows then the player can be a complete replacment and has no limits.  This happens very infrequently.

More common is a substitute, a substitute can be approved by the umpires for any injury, worsening of existing injury or exceptional circumstances.

A substitute, may not bat, bowl or captain the team.  In the 2017 laws it was changed to allow the substitute to keep wicket.

If a batsmen needs a substitute they can have a runner to run for them but this has to be a player who is nominated and they should have batted.

There has been a new playing condition added for international cricket that allows concussion replacements (https://www.timesnownews.com/sports/cricket/article/what-is-concussion-substitute-rule-heres-everything-on-iccs-new-set-of-guidelines/471184) first used for Steve Smith in the 2nd Ashes test 2019.

Answer (score 2):

Players can be replaced if they got injured otherwise after specific time they can not be replaced.

To answer of your second point, most players can be replaced if they are injured. But during the match you cannot replace the players because it is against the cricket rule.

Answer (score -1):

After the nomination, player replacement shall only be allowed with the consent of opposing captain.Once done replaced player can do his full duties as a nominated player.

Comment: Welcome to Sports! At the moment it's unclear if this is your opinion or the official rules...

Answer (score -1):

After nomination a player can be replaced at any time during the game.But it has to be with the consent of the opposing captain.

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. This answer currently doesn't provide anything new or beyond that of existing answers. Can you add some sort of explanation or reference to the rules?

Comment: And it isn't even fully correct any more with the addition of concussion substitutes to various forms of the game, which do _not_ need the consent of the opposing captain.